# How do I groupby one column in a dataframe and combine on another column no matter if there is text or blanks?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

I want to `groupby` on one column of a `Dataframe` and then combine any text in another column for the unique values of the first column (call_ID). The code should also delete any duplicates. My problem seems to be in deleting the duplicates. I tried the code below but it is not successful.

```
# Dataframe
dftest0 = pd.DataFrame(data ={'call_ID':[5423684,5423684,5423684,5423684],
'other_comb_words':['','','inspection','inspection']})

# Change datatype
dftest0['call_ID'] = dftest0['call_ID'].astype(str)

# groupby and combine text
dftest0['other_comb_words'] = dftest0.groupby(['call_ID'], as_index=False)
['other_comb_words'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))

# remove duplicates
dftest0 = dftest0.drop_duplicates(subset='other_comb_words')  
dftest0
```

`Dataframe` sample:

```
call_ID other_comb_words
5423684 
5423684 
5423684 inspection
5423684 inspection
```

Current output:

```
call_ID other_comb_words
5423684 inspection inspection
```

Desired output:

```
call_ID other_comb_words
5423684 inspection
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your line that drop duplicates also above your groupby line but without parameters (I added more data as example to confirm the expected result):

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe
dftest0 = pd.DataFrame(
    data ={'call_ID':[5423684,5423684,5423684,5423684,5423684,1234567],
    'other_comb_words':['','','inspection','inspection','example_1','example_2']})

# Change datatype
dftest0['call_ID'] = dftest0['call_ID'].astype(str)

# remove duplicates
dftest0 = dftest0.drop_duplicates()

# groupby and combine text
dftest0['other_comb_words'] = dftest0.groupby(
    ['call_ID'], as_index=False)['other_comb_words'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))

# remove duplicates from subsets
dftest0 = dftest0.drop_duplicates()

print(dftest0)
```

Result:

```
   call_ID       other_comb_words
0  5423684   inspection example_1
5  1234567              example_2
```

This is because you need to remove the duplicates from the original dataset, then in the groupby combination.